# Can 2 cellphones be allowed in a carry-on luggage

Tags: customs-and-immigration, cellphones, hand-luggage, philippines

Am I allowed to carry 2 used Samsung 3 cellphones traveling to the Philippines from US as a gift to my daughter and son?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be allowed? What are you concerned about?

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course. Many people carry two cellphones all the time, one for work and one for personal purposes.

Since you intend to leave the cellphones behind in Philippines, customs fees or import taxes may apply on arrival.

Answer (score 0):

After my research, you are able to take these 2 cellphones in your carry-on luggage, if they are in airplane mode because its restricted to have cellphone which is at (turn-on) profile with you but you also carry these things in your equipment which is in Separate part of plane........   [image: airline security]

Comment: Your answer would be easier to read if it included some commas, and if some of the periods would get up the nerve to show themselves before the end.

Comment: Hi. I tried to spell check your answer and make it more readable, but I am a bit confused on what you want to say with this " because its restricted to have on cellphone with you but you also carry these things in your equipment which is in Separate part of plane........ " Are you saying, that you are only allowed to have 1 phone in your hand luggage in air plane mode? If yes, do you have a source for that? Can you reformulate the answer, so that it is easier to understand. (You  can use the 'edit' link under your answer to change it)

Comment: no dear...! i did`t say that i want to say that you are only allowed to have cellphones with you in plane with switched off profile (airplane mode), its doesn`t matter how many cellphone you carry with you

Comment: so that`s why i attached an picture because with this you understand my answer very well

Comment: otherwise thank you dear for making my answer reliable\